# Selecting nvarchar 'like' in a left join - inner join combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have a query that returns results based on a dynamic set of conditions

```
DataTable Items:
    ID   Title
    1    Some title
    2    Some other title
..etc..
```

.

```
DataTable Tags:
    ID   Tag
    1    'a1c'
    1    'a1d'
    2    'a2c'
..etc..
```

My current search Query:

```
select * from dbo.Items i
LEFT JOIN dbo.tags t
on i.ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN @input in
on (in.[input] = t.Tag or in.[input] is null)
```

An input would be something like:

```
DECLARE @input as inputTable_type
INSERT INTO @input VALUES ('a1c')
```

What I would like to do is use a value like 'a1%' as an input, but when I try that, I get no results (although I do know that a query such as the following does work):

```
select * from dbo.Items i
INNER JOIN dbo.tags t
on i.ID = t.ID
and t.Tag like ('a1%')
```

Unfortunately, I want to keep it a static query, and as far as I know, I need the LEFT JOIN - INNER JOIN combination that I have in order to be able to pass `VALUES (NULL)` into the stored procedure.

Thanks for any thoughts and help, and let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: It's a bad idea to do a join on an unspecified table, which is basically what you are asking to do.  If you have two tables, a1a and a1b, which would you join?  Are you ok with not joining a1b?  SQL won't add extra joins for you if you use a wildcard.

Comment: @JNK - I guess I may have not been clear enough in my description, as I was trying to greatly simplify the query that I'm actually using. I'll be providing a list of inputs (hence why it is in a user-defined table type), so I would be passing inputs of `'a1c', 'a1%', 'a2c'`, etc.

Comment: No I understand, I guess what I am getting at is if there are 2 tables that fit your criteria (since you want to use the LIKE comparison), how do you want the query to react?  It won't run for multiple tables in the same criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to store 'a1%' in your `@input` table, store just 'a1', then I think the (untested) code below will give you what you want.

```
select * 
    from dbo.Items i
        LEFT JOIN dbo.tags t
            INNER JOIN @input in
                on in.[input] = left(t.Tag, len(in.[input]))
            on i.ID = t.ID
    where (t.ID is not null or not exists(select 1 from @input))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this looks great, as it is giving me the results I need, but if I were to not have a `tag` for a given item, I'm still receiving NULL values in my result set even though I've specified a Tag to search by...

Comment: @Brett: I added a `where` clause that should help with that.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I had done something similar, I hadn't thought about it too much before I commented. This solution worked great for me, but I was wondering if you would be able to explain the difference between putting the `ON i.ID = t.ID` condition for the left join BEFORE the INNER JOIN versus AFTER the INNER JOIN? I noticed the results will include NULL values from `Tags` in your code, but NOT include NULL values from `Tags` if the ON condition is moved.

Comment: @Brett: You can think of the version I wrote as a `LEFT JOIN` to a derived table that consists of the `INNER JOIN` of the other two `(dbo.tags t INNER JOIN @input in...)` Since it sounds like you don't want the NULLs in your case, your version would be the appropriate one in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already playing funny games with the outer joined table, why not extend the games?  The simplest version is to replace the equality with LIKE; the next simplest version is to add an OR term:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Items i
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tags t ON i.ID = t.ID
 INNER JOIN @input  in ON (t.Tag = in.[input] OR
                           t.Tag LIKE in.[input] OR
                           in.[input] IS NULL)
```

The next grade up in sophistication (or do I mean 'complication'?) is to add a second column to the @input table which indicates the comparison to perform:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Items i
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tags t ON i.ID = t.ID
 INNER JOIN @input  in ON ((in.[type] = '=' AND t.Tag = in.[input]) OR
                           (in.[type] = '%' AND t.Tag LIKE in.[input]) OR
                           in.[input] IS NULL)
```

I've chosen to call the extra column 'type' and the value in it is a single character, using '=' to indicate an equality join and '%' to indicate a LIKE join.